# Bootstrap open Modal AND Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a way to open a modal as well as the underlying hyperlink.
So if my code looks like this:

```
<a class="btn pull-right" target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_div" data-remote="false">something</a>
```

I want to open the Modal as well as the link to "www.example.com"...
Does anybody have an idea of how to accomplish this?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Please provide a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/9d24L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the `.click` handler for your link, remove `data-` attributes and toggle `.modal()` with javascript. 
I think that bootstrap handler for clicking on anchors with `data-` attributes for modals and other plugins uses `preventDefault()`, that is why you just can't use `href="http://www.example.com"`.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3314/)